# NetBeans : Can't build Java project

Tags: ubuntu, java, programming

I installed today on my old developer PC NetBeans (the newest) and I cloned my repo from BitBucket (I began coding with NetBeans on Windows 7). I tried to make a clean build, but the compiler has outputed an error.

Output log:

```
ant -f "/home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build
Updating property file: /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build/classes
Created dir: /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build/empty
Created dir: /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 17 source files to /home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/build/classes
javac: invalid target release: 1.8
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
/home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/nbproject/build-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/noel/NetBeansProjects/ProtonBlazt (Git)/nbproject/build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

build-impl.xml here : http://pastebin.com/kt3G9dPS

I hope anyone can solve the problem.

Greetings

miny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but you should really read each and every line of the output log to understand why the error happened. This is the error line:

```
javac: invalid target release: 1.8
```

It means you do not have a JDK for Java version 1.8, I would suggest [googling](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=javac%3A%20invalid%20target%20release%3A%201.8) this error, that way you would for example see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766591/javac-invalid-target-release-1-8).